# Rails App session error, can't signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating my first solo project with rails and users can't seem to sign in. I call my sign in method immediately after the user is created, but if they sign out the app will not let them sign back in. Here is what I am getting when submitting the sign in form

Here is the error message

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

it says it is in line 6 of the sessions controller but I think something else is wrong

Sessions Controller

```
   class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

    def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end


def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

Login form

```
    <h1>Sign in</h1>
    <br />

    <%= form_tag sessions_path  do  %>

      <%= label_tag :email %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag :email %><br />

      <%= label_tag :password %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag :password %><br />

      <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "button" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
```

Routes

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sessions/new"

  get "users/new"

  resources :posts
  resources :static_pages
  resources :users
  resources :sessions



  root to: 'posts#index'

  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signup',   to: 'users#new' 
  match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/projects', to: 'static_pages#projects'

end
```

Also here is the rake:routes

```
    sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)          sessions#new
       users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)             users#new
           posts GET    /posts(.:format)                 posts#index
                 POST   /posts(.:format)                 posts#create
        new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)             posts#new
       edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)        posts#edit
            post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#show
                 PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#update
                 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)             posts#destroy
    static_pages GET    /static_pages(.:format)          static_pages#index
                 POST   /static_pages(.:format)          static_pages#create
 new_static_page GET    /static_pages/new(.:format)      static_pages#new
edit_static_page GET    /static_pages/:id/edit(.:format) static_pages#edit
     static_page GET    /static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#show
                 PUT    /static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#update
                 DELETE /static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#destroy
           users GET    /users(.:format)                 users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                 users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)             users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)        users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)             users#show
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)             users#destroy
            root        /                                posts#index
          signin        /signin(.:format)                sessions#new
          signup        /signup(.:format)                users#new
         signout DELETE /signout(.:format)               sessions#destroy
           about        /about(.:format)                 static_pages#about
        projects        /projects(.:format)              static_pages#projects
```

Sessions Helper

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def sign_out
        self.current_user = nil
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you tail the logs and tell us what is getting posted for that action?
My suspicion is that it's not coming through as `params[:session][:email]` but instead as `params[:email]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your view markup, it looks like you should be looking for..

params[:email].downcase, instead of params[:session][:email].downcase.

The form tag isn't scoped to a session object so the params aren't matching correctly. Drop the session in the params code and you should be ok.